# Will upgrading to a faster server make my videos load / stream quicker for users?

Tags: linux, godaddy, streaming

General question that even a godaddy tech couldn't really answer for me. Im making a website with lots of video on it, most are embedded from youtube. I know, to stream videos, I should upgrade to a faster / better server. I just don't know why, or what that means. Will the videos actually load faster for the user? If I upgrade to a dedicated server should I host the videos on my server or will they still run faster being embedded from youtube(since youtube probably spends lots of money on its servers and streaming quality).

I know, on the users end, it really depends on how fast their internet connection is, but will upgrading my server allow the users computer to receive the files from the server at a higher rate therefor making the videos actually load quicker, or something... lol?

Also, if upgrading a server helps with streaming video, my jpg's / png's should download to a users computer quicker as well right? So a full page image might not flash, as it loads, as it would with a default / starter godaddy server (just as an example)...?

Answer (score 2):

> Im making a website with lots of video on it, most are embedded from youtube.

No, you make a website then with a lot of HTML - the video is not your problem so to say (as it is coming from youtube).

If you embedd a video from youtube your server is not involved at all in showing the video - all you deliver is the HTML code that makes the browser then contact youtube to show the video. You do NEVER stream anything (as in: no video data) from your server.

Also, what is upgrading?

If I get a bigger engine into my car, it does not turn it into a truck. There are multiple dimensions of speed on a server (CPU, RAM, INTERNET BANDWIDTH) and unless you identify the problem (which is trivial for anyone who should handle a server) then yes, if there is a bottleneck and you fix it - then things get faster.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Im wondering if theres a chart that shows how fast youtube's servers are so I can understand at what point there is a cost benefit to hosting my own files or staying with youtube... say its beneficial to use youtube if you have a couple hundred HD videos you want on your site and want to cut costs but if your trying to create a streaming platform like netflix, you upgrade the servers... Do you know of any browser plugins, or things of the sort, that will test video download / streaming speed from a server so I can see, after an upgrade, the change in speed?